# ClickOnce having Before and After Updates

Tags: c#, wpf

at the moment my application updates perfectly before the application starts. If there's a new version, the prompt will appear. Some of my clients will not restart the program, they simply would log-out and leave it running in the background. How can I set up clickonce to have the program update before application is running and check for updates every 4 hours.

I can see there's two options in Application Updates - After application starts and before application starts. But I'm looking for something that's a combination of both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have implemented this the following way:

```
public void StartSearchForUpdates()
{
    if(!ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
    {
        return;
    }
    bool updateAvailable = false;
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (!updateAvailable)
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromHours(4));
            updateAvailable = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CheckForUpdate();
            if (UpdateAvailable)
            {
                ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.UpdateAsync();
                ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.UpdateCompleted += OnUpdatedCompleted;
            }
        }
    });
}

private void OnUpdatedCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    AvailableVersion = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.UpdatedVersion;
}
```

Comment: Do you know if the software has to be restarted ?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do it with click once.

I suggest you to create a background thread in your app that check if there is a new version of the app...